# Mobile Safari (iPhone) CSS vertical centering/line-height CSS issues

Tags: iphone, css, mobile, mobile-safari

Got an issue I've been trying to solve without much luck for a while across various projects.

I've got some `div`s with text inside that is centered with CSS using `display: block` and `line-height`. I also tried with `padding` and a fixed height. Typically, these are setup as either just headers, or sometimes buttons.

Either way, I always seem to have an offset on the top from vertical center in the mobile safari browser that I don't get in ANY web browser (it's perfectly vertically aligned in a desktop browser). I can alter the setting to `center` in the mobile browser, but this throws out all the other browsers and this is a responsive design.

Has anyone experienced this issue?

I've got `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;` but that doesn't seem to be related to this issue.

So far my hack work around is to have devices only css which sets a different `line-height`, but as you can imagine, that's a horrible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article has some great information on many different options for centering content when you don't know anything about the widths and heights:

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

It builds on from user1002464's answer quite well.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` for the div containing the text

Comment: The text seems to be sitting not quite in the center with the vertical align as middle (there's an offset so it's sitting below the center point). Any ideas?

Any idea for the background image position - that's different on the phone as well.

Comment: can you host a jsfiddle example, so that i can see what exactly is the issue