# Center link text in a circle

Tags: html, css

I have a cicle created with CSS that is positioned absolutely in it's container.  The text in the circle is a link.  Can this link be centered vertically and horizontally inside the circle?  I am testing on Firefox and Chrome with the browser set to 320px wide.  I am also testing on the iOS Safari Mobile.

Here is a fiddle I made to demonstrate where I am at with this at the moment:

http://jsfiddle.net/rFZBA/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="circle">
        <a href="#">+</a>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.container {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#999;
}    

.circle {
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;
    top:50px;

    height:1.25em;/** 20px / 16px = 1.25em **/
    width:1.25em;/** 20px / 16px = 1.25em **/

    padding:0.75em;  /** 12px / 16px = 0.75em  **/
    border-radius:1.375em;  /* Half of 44px is  22px :: 22px / 16px = 1.375em **/   
    background-color:#4d90fe;
    color:#FFF;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    text-align:center;  
}

.circle > a {
    color:#FFF; 
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:2.5em;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I was able to center it based on your code by changing the top/left to:

    position:absolute;
    left:130px;
    top:28px;

Comment: @Daniel It's not about centring the circle, but the plus character in the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply apply the `.circle` to the `<a>` tag: http://jsfiddle.net/rFZBA/16/

And then do some little modifications so that the size is good.

It's automatically centered here as the border is around the text and the text is of quadratic size (a single `+`). Also, don't forget to make the line-height equal to the height and with, so that's centered vertically.

Comment: Thanks!  This is really close.  It looks great on my desktop firefox browser, but when I test it on Mobile Safari in iOS the "+" is not quite veritcally centered.  I wonder why there is a difference.

Comment: I've got iOS 6 iPhone as well. The "+" sign appears to be a little lower in the red circle, slightly off the center.

Comment: @Mdd which red circle? the only one is blue. It's exactly centered when I try to count the pixels.

Comment: @Mdd At least when I look in the fiddle. Are you sure you have copied everything?

Comment: Sorry about that, I am updating the fiddle and changed it the color to red for more contrast to what is being centered.  I will see if I can find another iPhone with iOS 6.  On mine the + sign is a little lower than the center of the circle.  Could the box-shadow be the reason why it appears this way to me?

Comment: @Mdd yeah to me it appears also so. But it is really centered, even if I didn't think this ;-)

Comment: Thanks.  I found this post that has the exact same issue only there is no answer yet:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328762/mobile-safari-iphone-css-verticle-centering-line-height-css-issues

Answer (score 1):

use line-height and text-align

```
.circle > a {
    color:#FFF; 
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:2.5em;
    font-weight:bold;
line-height:0.625em /* wich is 1.25em (2.5/5X1.25)  or use : 1.25rem; */;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/rFZBA/10/

```
.circle > a {
    color:#FFF; 
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:2.5em;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:10.5px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it centered by adding `display: table;` to `.circle` and `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` to `.circle a`; however, it created an oblong object rather than a pure circle. Here's the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Nirvanachain/rFZBA/

If I change the font size of the `<a>` to 16px, then you have exactly what you want.